# cfargument is not passing in cfoutput with cfquery

Tags: coldfusion

I could not use student_id in cfoutput with query. My argument didn't pass in getStudentAnswers function. How can I do this?

I want to create JSON and need to add question and questions' answers near exam like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "7",
    "type": "2",
    "question_id": "20",
    "question": "Write a summary by answering the questions below: * What is convergence? * What will be the implications of convergence on classical media? on users? * Which devices/media forms do you think will converge nowadays/in the future? * What will be the opportunities and threats emerged by the convergence?",
    "question_type": "0",
    "answer": "",
    "name": "Assignment3ver2",
    "deadline_date": "2014-11-22 00:00:00.0"
  }
```

**Functions:**

```
<cffunction name="getQuestion" > 
<cfargument name="exam_id" type="string" required="true" >
<cfargument name="student_id" type="string" required="true" >

<cfset mert="#student_id#" >

<cfquery dataSource="mobileCourse" name="questselect"> 
    SELECT id,question,question_type FROM dbo.Questions WHERE exam_id=#exam_id#
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="questselect">
    "question_id": "#id#",
    "question": "#question#",
    "question_type": "#question_type#",
    #getStudentAnswers(mert, id, question)#
</cfoutput>

<cfreturn />
```

```
<cffunction name="getStudentAnswers" > 
<cfargument name="student_id" type="string" required="true" >
<cfargument name="question_id" type="string" required="true" >
<cfargument name="question" type="string" required="true" >

<cfquery dataSource="mobileCourse" name="questselecta"> 
    SELECT * FROM dbo.ANSWERS WHERE question_id=#question_id# AND  student_id=#student_id# 
</cfquery>

<cfif #questselecta.recordcount# gte 1>
<cfoutput query="questselecta">
    "answer": "#answer#",
</cfoutput>
<cfelse>
    "answer": "",
</cfif>

<cfreturn />
```

Comment: ???  There's lots of things wrong here, I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to ask. It might help to see your getStudentAnswers function too.  You need to var scope mert and questselect.  You should use cfqueryparam.  Your getQuestion function should really return a struct or JSON string or whatever you're trying to do, than output it inside the function. You should scope your variables, e.g. arguments.student_id, questselect.id etc.

Comment: I have just edited my question.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't pass in getStudentAnswers function"? What `exam_id` and `student_id` values are you passing into the function? What actually happens when you run the code - an error, wrong results? Having said that - a) It does not look like you even need two functions, just a single query with an outer `JOIN` b) Do not roll your own JSON. Construct the desired data structure and use `serializeJSON`

Comment: When i use #getStudentAnswers(mert, id, question)# function, i can use id and question in that function but mert is null in that function.

Comment: CF does not have nulls for the most part. Do you mean it is empty? You still did not answer the earlier question: what is the actual `exam_id` and `student_id` values passed into the first function? Without knowing more, there are a bunch of reasons why the id is empty 1) you might be passing an empty id into `getQuestion` 2) there might not be a matching record in your ANSWER table. But again, from what you have described the above code is not an efficient way to get the job done. Instead run a single query with a JOIN, build a structure with the results, then return it with `serializeJSON`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question. However, even ignoring the errors mentioned in the comments, the code above is not an efficient way to get the job done. It is not necessary to run a separate query for *each* question in the exam. Just run a single query using a JOIN instead. Since you appear to want *all* questions, even ones without an answer, make it an [OUTER JOIN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx).

<sub>Note: Never use raw parameters in a `cfquery` because it puts your database at risk for sql injection. Instead use `cfqueryparam` with whichever `cfsqltype` matches actual data types of your columns ([see documentation matrix](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f6f.html)).</sub>

```
<!--- adjust cfsqltypes as needed --->
<cfquery name="yourQueryName" ....>
   SELECT q.id, q.question, q.question_type, a.answer, ... other columns 
   FROM   Questions q LEFT JOIN Answers a 
                ON  a.question_id = q.question_id 
                AND a.student_id = <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.student_id#" 
                                                 cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
   WHERE  q.exam_id = <cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.exam_id#" 
                                    cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">

</cfquery>
```

Once you have the query results, use it to build your result object. The exact structure depends on your application, but assuming there can be multiple questions - an array of structures would be a good example.

<sub>Be sure to properly scope all variables. All function local variables should be `var/local` scoped to prevent potential threading issues: **that includes query names**.</sub>

```
<!--- localize all variables --->
<cfset var yourQueryName = "">
<cfset var resultArray = "" >
<cfset var data = "" >

.... run query ....

<!--- first initialize the array --->
<cfset resultArray = []>

<!--- loop through your query and build an array of structures --->
<cfloop query="yourQueryName">
    <!--- create new structure to store current question --->
    <cfset data = {}>
    <cfset data["question_id"] = yourQueryName.question_id>
    <cfset data["question"] = yourQueryName.question>
    <cfset data["answer"] = yourQueryName.answer>
    ... other keys ....

    <!--- append the question to your array --->
    <cfset arrayAppend(resultArray, data)>

</cfloop>
```

Finally, use `serializeJSON` to return the array of structures in JSON format:

```
  <cfreturn serializeJSON(resultArray)>
```